# Event Handler for Dynamically Created CheckBox

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-5, tcheckbox

I wrote a C++ program using Borland C++ Builder 5.  The program dynamically creates an array of `TCheckBox` objects.  I have tried to write an `OnClick` event handler that would identify which checkbox is being clicked and execute some instructions based on that.  My event handler is based on similar posts to this website, but I cannot seem to make it work.

Here is the (abbreviated) code

```
// Header declaration
void __fastcall CBoxClick(TObject *Sender); 
// End Header
```

```
// CBoxClick function (the event handler)

void __fastcall CBoxClick(TObject *Sender){
    if (dynamic_cast<TCheckBox*>(Sender)!=NULL){
        //Do stuff
    }
    else{
        Form1 -> Debug -> Text = "Object is not a TCheckBox";         
    }
}

void ChkBoxInit(void){
    int i;                                            //Loop counter index
    TCheckBox* ChkBx[NCARDS];                         //Define array of type checkboxes
    for(i = 0; i < NCARDS; i++){                      //Initalize each checkbox
        ChkBx[i] = new TCheckBox(Form1);              //Create a new checkbox
        ChkBx[i] -> Parent = Form1;                   //Define parent of checkbox
        ChkBx[i] -> Tag = i;                          //Set value of Tag to index
        //  Other CheckBox parameters here such as Height, Width, Top, Left, Name are here
        //  Next, call event handler. I've tried the following 2 statements with the comment results
        ChkBx[i] -> OnClick = CBoxClick(ChkBx[i]);    //  Results in E2109: Not an allowed type
        ChkBx[i] -> OnClick = CBoxClick;              /* Alternate try - Results in E2034: Cannot convert
                                                        'void (_fastcall *)(TObject *)' to 
                                                        'void (_fastcall * (_closure )(TObject *))(TObject *)'  */
    }                                                 //End of for loop
}                                                     //End of function
```

Answer (score 0):

### `CBoxClick()` is not a member of your Form class.

Within your cpp file, the compiler sees it as a standalone function.  That is what the error message is complaining about when the assignment of the `OnClick` event fails (non-static class methods have the `__closure` attribute, non-members do not).

Make sure `CBoxClick()` is declared **inside** your Form class in the header file:

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
    ...
public:
    ...
    void __fastcall CBoxClick(TObject *Sender); // <-- add this
    ...
};
```

And then change this line in your cpp file:

```
void __fastcall CBoxClick(TObject *Sender){
```

To this instead:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::CBoxClick(TObject *Sender){
```

And then change your assignment of the `OnClick` event from this:

```
ChkBx[i]->OnClick = CBoxClick;
```

To this instead (since `ChkBoxInit()` itself appears to not be a member of the Form class, either):

```
ChkBx[i]->OnClick = Form1->CBoxClick;
```

The first syntax you tried (`OnClick = CBoxClick(ChkBx[i]);`) is just plain wrong, as you are actually *calling* `CBoxClick()` and then trying to assign its `void` return value to `OnClick`, which obviously will not work.  You need to assign the *address* of `CBoxClick()` to `OnClick`, and that will work only for non-static class methods, not for standalone functions (well, it CAN be done, but it requires different code involving a type-cast hack utilizing the `TMethod` struct).

Also, you should not be using `dynamic_cast`.  Since you know the `Sender` will always be a `TCheckBox`, use `static_cast` instead:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::CBoxClick(TObject *Sender){
    TCheckBox *cb = static_cast<TCheckBox*>(Sender);
    //Do stuff with cb...
}
```

**UPDATE**: Now, with that said, a better option is to get rid of `ChkBoxInit()` altogether and do the array initialization inside the Form's own constructor instead:

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
    ...
private:
    ...
    void __fastcall CBoxClick(TObject *Sender); // <-- moved here
    ...
public:
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent *Owner); // <-- constructor
    ...
};
```

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    TCheckBox* ChkBx[NCARDS];                         //Define array of type checkboxes
    for(int i = 0; i < NCARDS; i++){                  //Initalize each checkbox
        ChkBx[i] = new TCheckBox(this);               //Create a new checkbox
        ChkBx[i] -> Parent = this;                    //Define parent of checkbox
        ChkBx[i] -> Tag = i;                          //Set value of Tag to index
        //  Other CheckBox parameters here such as Height, Width, Top, Left, Name are here
        //  Next, setup event handler
        ChkBx[i]->OnClick = CBoxClick;
    }                                                 //End of for loop
}        

void __fastcall TForm1::CBoxClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TCheckBox *cb = static_cast<TCheckBox*>(Sender);
    // Do stuff with cb...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I modified the code as you indicated.  I also modified the header to add the TForm1 scope but it did not compile, giving an error message E2316: 'CBoxClick' is not a member of 'TForm1'  How can I make CBoxClick a member of TForm1?

Comment: Do not add `TForm1::` in the header file. `CBoxClick` needs to actually be **inside** the Form's `class` declaration.  See the update to my answer.

Comment: I've been unsuccessful so far so I went back to your original suggestion as I noticed that I had not implemented it correctly.  Below is code from the header file, the event handler code and a simplified test routine which creates only a single checkbox, not an array of checkboxes.  It still does not work, giving a build error of E2034 Cannot convert 'void (_fastcall TForm1::*)(TObject *)' to 'void (_fastcall * (_closure )(TObject *))(TObject *)' at the line which assigns the OnClick event to CBoxClick.

Comment: @Doug the code I gave in my answer works fine, so you must not be applying it to your code correctly. Please edit your question to show your latest code

Comment: Sorry, I tried to do that but ran into problems with the editor and it submitted my comment before I was done.  Anyway, in the meantime I found a similar solution which I tried with success.  The change to your code was in the assignment of the OnClick event to the CBoxClick event handler as follows:               ChkBx[i] -> OnClick = Form1 -> CBoxClick;    //Assign OnClick event to Event Handler (CBoxClick)

Comment: Remy, thanks again for your help.  Below is the working code.  It is based on your first response with 1 modification to the event handler.  <br/>

Comment: @Doug please stop trying to put code in comments.  [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51976382/edit) instead, or post an answer if you have something that works.

Answer (score 0):

Remy - I'm still having trouble using the editor.  Here is the working code which is based on your first response with one small change.  Thank you for your help.

`//  .h File----------------

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
        TButton *Deal;
        TButton *Reset;
        TButton *Help;
        TButton *Quit;
        TEdit *Debug;
        void __fastcall QuitClick(TObject *Sender);
        void __fastcall ResetClick(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
  __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
  void __fastcall CBoxClick(TObject *Sender);  //CheckBox Event Handler prototype
};
```

// .cpp File ----------------

```
  void ChkBoxInit(void){
    int i;                                         //Loop counter index
    TCheckBox* ChkBx[NCARDS];                      //Define array of type checkbox
    for(i = 0; i < NCARDS; i++){                   //Initalize each checkbox
      ChkBx[i] = new TCheckBox(Form1);             //Create a new checkbox
      ChkBx[i] -> Parent = Form1;                  //Define parent of checkbox

// ..... Various parameters of ChkBx[i] go here (height, Width, Top, Left, etc.)

      ChkBx[i] -> Tag = i;                         //Use index value as tag
`     ChkBx[i] -> OnClick = Form1 -> CBoxClick;    //Assign OnClick event to CBoxClick
    }                                              //End of for loop
  }                                                //End of function


//  Event Handler ------------------

 void __fastcall TForm1::CBoxClick(TObject *Sender){
   if (static_cast<TCheckBox*>(Sender)!=NULL){
     Form1 -> Debug -> Text =  (static_cast<TCheckBox*>(Sender) -> Name);
   }
   else{
     Form1 -> Debug -> Text = "Object is not a TCheckBox";
   }
 }
```